# Prove trigonometric identity.

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation

How would one go about proving the identity
$$
\cot \frac{A}{2} - \tan\frac{A}{2} \equiv 2\cot A
$$

I know that $\tan 2A = \dfrac{2\tan A}{1 - \tan^2 A}$ but it is leading me nowhere when implementing it.

Comment: Use \equiv for $\equiv$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cot(A/2) - \tan(A/2) = \frac{1}{\tan (A/2)} - \tan(A/2) = \frac{1-\tan^2(A/2)}{\tan(A/2)}=$$
$$=2\frac{1-\tan^2(A/2)}{2\tan(A/2)}=\frac{2}{\frac{2\tan(A/2)}{1-\tan^2(A/2)}}=\frac{2}{\tan(A)}=2\cot(A)$$

Comment: I don't understand your second last step. I get $cotA - tanA$ instead of $\frac{2}{tanA}$

Comment: See if is better to understand now.

Comment: Much better now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** In

$$\cot(A)=\frac{\cos(A)}{\sin(A)}$$

plug

$$\cos(A)=\cos^2(\frac{A}{2})-\sin^2(\frac{A}{2})$$

and

$$\sin(A)=2\sin(\frac{A}{2})\cos(\frac{A}{2}).$$

to get the result.